# About Pointer in C Language

Tags: c

```
struct Data{
    char * str;
};
int main(){
    struct Data p;
    char mystr[6];
    p.str = mystr;
    char s[] = "cs120";
    char * j = p.str; 
    for(char * i = s; *i != '\0'; i++){
        *j = *i;
        j++;
    }
    *j = '\0';
    printf("%p: %s", j+1, p.str);
    return 0;
}
```

This is a code to print the address and the string. But, I do not understand what "p.str" does.

Does it mean that converting p(pointer in Data struct) to a string?
Also, does "p.str = mystring" mean that p is addressed to mystr?

Comment: It's valid, but I wonder why the program is printing the address after the end of the `mystr` array.

Comment: Don't use "smart quotes" when writing code. C only allows ASCII quotes.

Comment: `"p.str = mystring" mean that p is addressed to mystr?` No. `p` is an instance of `struct Data` and has an address of its very own - unrelated to the address of `mystring`. Now... after the assignment `p.str = mystr;`, the address held (pointed to) by `p.str` is the address of `mystr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p` is not a pointer, it's a `struct Data` variable. `p.str` is the member of this structure, it's a `char *` pointer.

```
p.str = mystr;
```

copies the address of the `mystr` array into this pointer (an array variable decays to a pointer to its first element in this context).

Comment: Thank you. Then `.str` is the pointer in the struct? Because I do not understand where the `.str` came from.

Comment: Yes, that's how you access structure members. If you don't understand it, you should review the section on structures in your textbook or tutorial.